# formulate the objective function in gurobi

Tags: python-2.7, math, linear-programming, gurobi

I am using Gurobi 7.0 in python 2.7 now, I have troubles in inferring the optimize object in such situation:

```
latency_matrix = model.addVars(
    M,
    M,
    lb=0,
    vtype=GRB.INTEGER,
    name='delay')
status_list = model.addVars(
    M,
    vtype=GRB.BINARY,
    name='status')
```

The latency_matrix and status_list both chages with other vars in the model, so they can not be known before running the model.
The matrix is an upper triangular matrix

The objective fuction I need is :
for each continuous pair of 1 in status_list, mark their index as i and j. calculate the sum of latency_matrix[i][j]

Example:
if status_list is [1,0,1,1,0,0,1], then the index pairs we get are:
(0,2),(2,3),(3,6).
So the sum will be **latency_matrix[0][2] + latency_matrix[2][3] + latency_matrix[3][6]**

ps. I am not sure if this function can be solved in Gurobi. I am new to math programming area.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The general approach is introducing auxiliary binary variables activating the lookup in your matrix (so the objective becomes the product of a binary-matrix and your matrix where only some terms are nonzero).

Comment: sorry i don't quite understand this method, is it convenient for you to make an example ?

Comment: It's not trivial (and probably not that compact too; code-wise). The general idea is not far away from other techniques like indicator-constraints. I won't tackle this right now, but i would not be surprised to see some other (specific) user to do this.

Comment: what about posting the question on the Gurobi google group?